# Iam unable to set PS1 variable in ksh shell

Tags: ksh

Below command to set the PS1 doesn't work for me

here is my shell:-

[u@h w]$echo $SHELL
/bin/ksh93

command:-

```
PS1="[\u@\h \w]\$"
```

returned output:-
[u@h w]$

Expected output:-
Linux@LinuxDistro /home/sohil$

Answer (score 0):

in ksh `\u` etc won't work. You have to use something like

```
 PS1='[$(id -un)@$(hostname -s) $PWD]$ '
```

Use single quotes, otherwise the prompt will not change with each command.

Or if you want to always show the initial user and hostname

```
PS1="[$(whoami)@$(hostname -s) \$PWD]$ "
```